# How can I trigger an update of Azure DevOps pipeline agent major version by script?

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to automate the update of major version on self-hosted agent, by script. I have searched the docs for Azure DevOps REST API to achive this but no luck. I found a solution online that requires you to reinstall the agent on every machine, which is not what I am after. Anyone have a clue? Is there a way to achieve this through the REST API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to achieve this through the REST API?

The answer is yes.

We could use the REST API [Agents - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/agents/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to update the version of the agent.

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{poolId}/agents/{agentId}?api-version=5.1
```

We do not provide the request body for this REST API.

To get the `poolId`, we could use the REST API [Pools - Get Agent Pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/pools/get%20agent%20pools?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/pools?api-version=5.1
```

As the result:

[image]